# Displaying Unknown characters while creating pdf ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, pdf, symbols

After creating pdf unknown symbols are displaying.

%PDF-1.4 %���� 1 0 obj <>stream x���wTT��Ͻwz��0)C� �7��Da�`(34�!�EDA�"��"�"���`�� ��`QQy3�Vt�彗��g}k���=g�}ֺ�����tX �4����J����c���`�23B=ÀH>n�L��"�7w�+7����t��I������؂��d��Pĩق�}F���1�(1�E������";����c�X|�v[�="ޚ%��qQ��-�["�L�qE�V��af�"��+IĦ"&��B�D�)�+������Rn��|nb����ң���2�ޜ�T�@`�d�0�l�[zZ����?KF\[����f���F��f_�n�M�{�H��?���}���_z=�YQmv|����c3����4 )�[��W����%I Ȱ31���6�rX�������7�������(ݝ��� �⺱�SӅ|zf�š�y��q�_��0����sx��pєqy��v��\7�G���S�a؟�8�"Q>j�1����>��s@���7|8��ՉŹ�,�߳�e�%���9�-$�������H*P*@�#`l�=p��0VHi��A>��@ �v�jP@h'@8 .���:�n�`���`��a!2D� UH2��!�y@�P�A�B��&�*���:� �:]��B��=h��~���L���2� ��������p"�΃��p\����u�60Fc���Da�1k0����V�y� f3��b�Xl ����{�ǰ�C�q�[��3�y�q<\�ww7������Zx;| ���ŗ��]��8~� M�!8�Ʉ��*B��!��HT'���\�b�8� q���$C�'��bHB�v�a�y�=�+2��Mv&G����&�E�c�[ �����[b�D�D�Đ�I������*�<�Jɓ���Rx)m)7)��:��SR�R��i3�@�4�R��W�'e�2�22l�B�C2e�(E��FaQ6Q(�(�TU��CM��P���Sgded-e�esdkd�Ȏ�

My function is given below

```
private void GeneratePDF(string path, string fileName, bool download, string text)
    {

        byte[] pdf;
        var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 10, 30, 30);
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {

            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);




            PdfWriter writer1 = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
            // HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(document);
            string pcnt;
            pcnt = (writer1.CurrentPageNumber - 1).ToString();
            pcnt = pcnt.Substring(1);


                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path + fileName,FileMode.Create)); 



            StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
            document.Open();

          // ****ADDS CONTENTS TO PDF*****

                document.Add(NoTable);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            document.Close();
            pdf = output.ToArray();

            //after this, Code for Saving to Folder
        }
    }
```

Waiting for reply.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to pinpoint your problem more and give an example of the `unknown` symbols that are being displayed.

Comment: These characters are displaying after executing this function(generatpdf)

Comment: Where are these symbols displayed? On your asp page? or in a pdf viewer? If you are returning the array as a file to the asp page, make sure the mime type is `application/pdf` I would also recommend to post a smaller piece of code so more people will be interested in reading it ;)

Comment: Symbols are displaying at top of monitor,after that the page contents are displayed..here i m just generating the pdf and save in disc..

Comment: This very much looks like you have in your `//after this, Code for Saving to Folder` some debug code outputting the array `pdf` to stdout.